# nth derivative for Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

This is a homework question, and I came to a valid answer:
$\displaystyle(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{3}{2}-i)$

But I am loathe to believe my professor would have given us this something like this and I feel like there is a simpler way to do this, but I just can't see it.  Is there?

Comment: Simpler way than what? How did you solve it?

Comment: Calculated derivatives 1-6, looked for common elements, and generalized.  I noticed that the coefficient was repeated multiplication of $\frac{3-2(n)}{2}$, the exponent was much easier and more obvious.

Comment: There are some tricks for problems like this, but I doubt that there's anything more straightforward than that approach for this problem. Are you interested in finding more approaches in connection with taylor series or more systematic approaches on how to find formulas like this one?

Comment: Both options, really.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is what you are looking for but if $f(u)=u^r$ it is easy to see that:

$$f^{(n)}(u)=r(r-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(r-n+1)u^{r-n}=n!{r\choose n}u^{r-n}$$

Then you just take $u\leftarrow 1+x$ and $r\leftarrow 
1/2$ and get your result.

Answer (score 1):

Induction looks promising,
so I will try it.

The hypothesis is
$((1+x)^{1/2})^{(n)}
=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{3}{2}-i)
$.

If $n=0$,
this is
$(1+x)^{1/2}
=(1+x)^{1/2}
$,
which is true.

If
$n=1$,
this is
$((1+x)^{1/2})'
=(1+x)^{1/2-1}(\frac32-1)
$.
The left side is
$\frac12(1+x)^{-1/2}
$
and the right side is
$(1+x)^{1/2-1}(\frac32-1)
=(1+x)^{-1/2}(\frac12)
$
so they are equal.

Suppose
$((1+x)^{1/2})^{(n)}
=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{3}{2}-i)
$.

The derivative of
the left side is
$((1+x)^{1/2})^{(n+1)}
$.

The derivative of the right side is

$\begin{array}\\
(\frac{1}{2}-n)(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{3}{2}-i)
&=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-(n+1)}(\frac{1}{2}-n)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{3}{2}-i)\\
&=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-(n+1)}(\frac{3}{2}-(n+1))\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{3}{2}-i)\\
&=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-(n+1)}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(\frac{3}{2}-i)\\
\end{array}
$

This proves the result.